# NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003

Tags: html, ios, objective-c

I am trying to display video from DataServer url and it shows normally as webview but  when the clicked open fullscreen button it gives me this error: [Click button to see fullscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oqxza.png)

[I tired it with many ways](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kg2l3.png)

Comment: I don't understand your code. As I said previously, you wrote `NSDate *videoData` instead of `NSData *videoData`. Your video is a `UIImage`? It doesn't make sense. You shouldn't use `dataWitthContentOfURL:`, if the URL is a remote URL. Do you need special access to that video? Like a token, specific headers, etc.?

Comment: Because there is no videocontroller and UIvideocontroller that's why i am displaying on UIImage

Comment: yes exactly specific header with token

Comment: `dataWithContentOfURL:` does a simple GET, with no customization. You need to use `URLSession`, with a `URLRequest` that you can configure...

Comment: I added 2nd picture checked out. I tired too many ways but most common one was 1st

Comment: Could you stop posting screenshots, and copy/paste code? Also, your issue is unclear. You want an Image or a Video? Your need to use `NSURLSession` and `NSURLRequest` instead of `NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:` if that's an image at the end of the URL.